# Check if number exists, if it does - get another

Tags: android, string

I am using a database to show random message at the push of a button.

Every time the button is pushed, a random number is generated and displays a message that corresponds to that number.
Of course, the same message can appear twice as the same number can be generated twice.

So I am creating a string, and I am concatenating each number when the button is pushed.

If the new random number is in the String, then I want to get another number.  If that number is in that String, I want to get another number etc etc (Regression?).

I also want to have a global count that I can change, so if the String reaches a size of 9 numbers, it will be reset to "".

```
 String randomList; //global
    final int MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 9;

     Integer randomNumber = getRandomMessage(messages.size());


  if(randomList.length() > 0) 
  {

    if(!randoms.contains(randomNumber.toString()))
    {
            messageText.setText(messages.get(randomNumber));
    }                

  }
```

Comment: Use an ArrayList instead of the String. Even if you wish to use the String, you'll have to separate the individual indices. Imagine adding 1 in the first cycle, then 2, then 12. 12 will already be in the list.

Comment: Actually, seeing as he only needs or allows 9 numbers, I'm guessing he's only using numbers 1 to 9 :) But yeah, still, use an ArrayList of ints.

Comment: If you want to use a List or something, use a TreeSet or a HashSet because the contains method is quicker there.

Comment: what is messages is a list of string?

Comment: messages is an array of messages.  I want to show random messages form this liost whenevr a user clicks a button.  But I don't want to show the same message twice.  In fact, I don't want the same message to appear in 9 pushes of the button.  Then I don't mind if a previous message shows up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a boolean Array of 9 elements

```
boolean[] check = new boolean[9];
```

Everytime you use a number, set check[number] to true

```
void useNumber(int number){
     check[number] = true;
}
```

To check if you already used this number

```
boolean checkNumber(int number){
     return check[number];
}
```

To reset check

```
void resetCheck(){
     for(int i = 0; i < check.length; i++) check[i] = false;
}
```

Edit:
Get a string for a given number, resetCheck if necessary;

```
String getString(int number){
   if(usedString == check.length){
     resetCheck();
     usedString = 0;
   }
   if(checkNumber(number)){
     return getString(getRandomNumber());
   }else{
     usedString++;
     return strings[number];
   }
}
```

Comment: but if I checkNumber and it has been used, I would get another random number, its possible that this new number would already be used.  How would I keep checking the numbers until I get a number that hasnt been used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can better use a `boolean` array. You can store the boolean array with the `SharedPreferences` class. A `boolean` array is more flexible and you can retrieve the values in constant time. You can also easily make it larger when you have more random messages.

Comment: You want to track if a message is already displayed or not. This is a true/false question. A boolean would suffice and an `int` would be overkill. An `int` takes more memory than a `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple trick Hope this works for you

```
buttonRandom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Collections.shuffle(messages);
        messageText.setText(messages.get(0));

    }
});
```

Comment: This is not a solution, because you will shuffle the messages every time a button is clicked. He has already the same functionality and this will result in the exact same problem he already has. You could let this work if you shuffle it only once, and use a counter and increment it every time a new message has to be displayed.